# Dúvida com R: Pegar uma linha na coluna x que contenha um valor especifico e transformar em outra tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

boa noite.

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma tabela com 3 informações: curso, id_cresc, qt_alunos
Eu preciso encontrar as linhas que tem id_cresc = 0 para somar a qt_alunos de essas linhas onde id_cresc = 0.

Exemplo de db:

```
curso        id_cresc    qt_alunos
Pegagogia    0.05%          100
Agronomia    0%             20
Design       0%             50
```

Assim queria que a saída no R fosse ou já o somatório de qt_alunos (quando id_cresc for = 0%) ou somente a coluna qt_alunos, onde também id_cresc = 0%).

Desculpa pela forma da pergunta primeira vez que estou realmente usando está ferramenta para tirar dúvidas.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
```

Cria-se o dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(curso = c("Pegagogia", "Agronomia", "Design"),
           id_cresc = c("0.05%", "0%", "0%"),
           qt_alunos = c(100, 20, 50))
```

Se vc quer o resultado só com a soma:

- use `mutate()` aliado à `parse_number()` para converter uma coluna para o formato numérico;
- use `filter()` para filtrar apenas as observações que atendam às suas necessidades
- use `group_by()` para agrupar (nesse caso só vai ter um grupo mesmo);
- use `summarise()`  + `sum()` para obter uma coluna com a soma

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id_cresc = parse_number(id_cresc)) %>% 
  filter(id_cresc == 0) %>% 
  group_by(id_cresc) %>% 
  summarise(soma = sum(qt_alunos))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  id_cresc  soma
     <dbl> <dbl>
1        0    70
```

Se vc quer a somente a coluna "qt_alunos", onde  "id_cresc = 0%"

- use `mutate()` aliado à `parse_number()` para converter uma coluna para o formato numérico;
- use `filter()` para filtrar apenas as observações que atendam às suas necessidades
- use `select()` para selecionar sua variável de interesse

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id_cresc = parse_number(id_cresc)) %>% 
  filter(id_cresc == 0) %>% 
  select(qt_alunos)

# A tibble: 2 × 1
  qt_alunos
      <dbl>
1        20
2        50
```